# WordPress sidebar text widget

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm using the Showcase Sidebar with a Text widget. I've inserting some HTML and Text and want that Text widget to display. What PHP code do I insert into the sidebar.php template to show the Text widget and any other ones that I add? Ideal I would like to only load the first Text Widget in from the Showcase Sidebar

would the code look something like this?

```
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')
|| !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar2') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Are you using the standard wordpress text widget? If so, why not append it through the admin interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it would look something like code you posted:

```
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')
|| !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar2') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

, but -

The code that you posted will only work if you have defined and registered such a sidebar (named : **sidebar2**)

in your theme´s php you should have a register_sidebar() function call.

```
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'=> 'Sidebar 2',
        'id' => 'sidebar2',
    ));
}
```

you can even customize it further with other parameters like .

```
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">', 
    'after_widget' => '</li>',
    'before_title' => '<h2 class="offscreen">',
    'after_title' => '</h2>',
```

If your theme already have such a sidebar defined and registered , then the code you have posted will work and the front side will display all the widgets that you put to that sidebar (on the admin side) .
If it is not defined by your theme you will need to define it or ADD it to the definitions of other sidebars .

Read more on the codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes)  and [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-create-new-widget-area?replies=5) about defining sidebars.